# How to delete data from the session when rendering the page?

Tags: magento-1.9

I write the data to the session, then immediately redirect the user to the form where they are used to render the page, and at the moment when they were used to render, you need to delete the data from the session

```
   <?php

class RonisBT_Feedback_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function postAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($post) {

            $customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
            $feedback = Mage::getModel('feedback/block');

            $name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('name');
            $email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
            $phone = $this->getRequest()->getPost('phone');
            $user_agent = Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent();
            $remote_ip = Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr();
            $subject = $this->getRequest()->getPost('subject');
            $other_subject = $this->getRequest()->getPost('other_subject');
            $message = $this->getRequest()->getPost('message');
            $data = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $feedback->setData('name', $name);
            $feedback->setData('email', $email);
            $feedback->setData('phone', $phone);
            $feedback->setData('subject', $subject);
            $feedback->setData('other_subject', $other_subject);
            $feedback->setData('message', $message);
            $feedback->setData('status', RonisBT_Feedback_Model_Source_Status::UNREAD);
            $feedback->setData('user_agent', $user_agent);
            $feedback->setData('remote_ip', $remote_ip);
            $feedback->setData('created_at', $data);
            $feedback->setData('updated_at', $data);

            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            try {
                $validate = Mage::getModel('feedback/validation')->validation($feedback);
                if ($validate === true) {
                    $captcha = Mage::getModel('feedback/captcha')->captcha();
                    if ($captcha === true) {
                        //deleted data
//                        $customerSession->unsFeedbackName($name);
//                        $customerSession->unsFeedbackEmail($email);
//                        $customerSession->unsFeedbackPhone($phone);
//                        $customerSession->unsFeedbackMessage($message);

                        $feedback->save();

                        $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                        /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                        $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                            ->setReplyTo($email)
                            ->sendTransactional(
                                Mage::getStoreConfig(RonisBT_Feedback_Model_Source_Paths::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                                Mage::getStoreConfig(RonisBT_Feedback_Model_Source_Paths::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                                Mage::getStoreConfig(RonisBT_Feedback_Model_Source_Paths::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                                null,
                                array('data' => $feedback,
                                    'feedback_id' => $feedback->getId(),
                                )
                            );
                        if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                            throw new Exception();
                        }

                        $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.');
                        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                        return;
                    } else {
                        $errors[] = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Please check the reCAPTCHA field to continue.');
                        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                    }
                } else {
                    //save data to session
                    $customerSession->setFeedbackName($name);
                    $customerSession->setFeedbackEmail($email);
                    $customerSession->setFeedbackPhone($phone);
                    $customerSession->setFeedbackMessage($message);
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later');
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
        } else {
            $this->_redirect('feedback/index/index');
        }
    }
}
```

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout version="1.0.1">
    <feedback_index_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/customer.js</name></action>
            <block type="core/text" name="google.captcha">
            <action method="setText">
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script><script type="text/javascript"></script>]]>
                </text>
            </action>
            </block>
        </reference>


        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" template="feedback/index.phtml"/>
        </reference>

    </feedback_index_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a block in the Block folder of your module and implement getter methods for all fields like the following code:

```
class RonisBT_Feedback_Block_Yourblockname extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    private $feedbackName = "";
    private $email = "";

    public function getFeedbackName()
    {
        if ($this->feedbackName == ""){ 
            $this->feedbackName = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getFeedbackName();
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->unsFeedbackName();
        }
        return $this->feedbackName;
    }

    public function getFeedbackEmail()
    {
        if ($this->email == ""){ 
            $this->email = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getEmail();
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->unsEmail();
        }
        return $this->email;
    }

    //methods for the other fields...
}
```

Change the layout.xml and insert your block in the layout definition:

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="yourmodule/yourblockname" template="feedback/index.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Change the from template and replace all the getters where you access the session data with the setter of your block, e.g. for  FeedbackName `$this->getFeedbackName()`.

I hope that helps and you will get it run.

Comment: This is not quite that, I just need to delete the session when the user leaves the page, so that when he logged in after a while, there was no old data on it.

Comment: we write the data to the session, then we immediately redirect the user to the form where they are used to render the page, and at the moment when we used them for rendering we need to remove them from the session

Comment: When a customer logs out the session will be deleted, so you can't transfer the data to a new session. "When the user leaves the page" means it could also be the last action on your site so you have no action point at all. So in my opinion the safest way NOT to display the customer old data you don't want is to delete that data by the first get request to the page. Anyway you can try to create some observer code and hook in in session events like 'customer_session_init' or 'customer_login' and do there whatever meets your requirement

Comment: I edited the question and formulated it more clearly

Comment: OK, but you have only the controller code in your question. Anyway you even can call all the unset methods in your form at the end (so after all data has been used) and that should work. It is not nice, but it works. Nice would be to implement that logic in the block which renders the form.

Comment: So I can not understand where I call for deleting data from the session.
The page is rendered by me above, the question has been edited.

Comment: The page is usually rendered by a block which is configured somewhere in your layout xml. Your controller makes only redirects as far as I see. But I know only the controller and your form phtml file nothing in between - therefore I can't say more. From what I see I just can say put the lines at the end of the form phtml and it will work, but it's not nice :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90318/discussion-between---and-helgeb).